# ROUND inside COUNTIF in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use an operation on a range inside COUNTIF? Let's say I want to count all the occurrences where a range is less than 50 *after rounding*. Can I do that without creating an extra column?

This does not work (returns 0).

```
=COUNTIF(ROUND(scores); "<50")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `arrayformula()` wrapper to evaluate `round()` for every value, like this:

```
=arrayformula( countif( round(scores); "< 50" ) )
```

The formula assumes that every value in `scores` contains a number. In the event the range may also contain blanks or text strings, use `filter()`, like this:

```
=counta( iferror( filter(scores; isnumber(scores); round(scores) < 50) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As @doubleunary explained, you can use ARRAYFORMULA. Or may just be useful?: `=COUNTIF(scores;"<49.5")` If it's useful you'll get less calculations done

Comment: That is a great idea, but as given, the formula will not count the edge case correctly, and it uses an incorrect syntax.

Comment: Oh, yes, dummy me. I've corrected it! Thanks for the observation!

Comment: I'm afraid that still won't handle the edge case correctly. Use `<` and observe the locale.

Comment: Definitely not my day